# How do I get the position of an Event while iterating over it with an EventReader?

Tags: xml, rust

I want to use `xml::reader::EventReader` from `xml_rs`.

I need both the parsed events and their position in the XML file:

```
use xml::common::{Position, TextPosition};
use xml::reader::{EventReader};

fn main() {
    let s = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"\nencoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<ooo></ooo>\n";
    let xml = EventReader::new(s.as_bytes());
    for e in xml {
        println!("event: {:?}", e);
        println!("pos: {:?}", xml.position());
    }
}
```

But the compiler complains:

```
error[E0382]: borrow of moved value: `xml`
 --> src/main.rs:9:31
  |
6 |     let xml = EventReader::new(s.as_bytes());
  |         --- move occurs because `xml` has type `xml::reader::EventReader<&[u8]>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
7 |     for e in xml {
  |              ---
  |              |
  |              value moved here
  |              help: consider borrowing to avoid moving into the for loop: `&xml`
8 |         println!("event: {:?}", e);
9 |         println!("pos: {:?}", xml.position());
  |                               ^^^ value borrowed here after move
```

Without the second `println!` the code works.

```
[package]
name = "xmlproblem"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
xml-rs = "0.8"
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: FWIW [What is the r#“”# operator in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26611664/155423)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to implement iteration directly:

```
use xml::common::{Position};
use xml::reader::{EventReader, XmlEvent};

fn main() {
    let s = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"\nencoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<ooo></ooo>\n";
    let mut xml = EventReader::new(s.as_bytes());
    loop {
        let e = xml.next();
        println!("event: {:?}", e);
        println!("pos: {:?}", xml.position());
        match e {
            Ok(XmlEvent::EndDocument) => {
                break;
            }
            _ => {}
        }
    }
}
```